# Would each universe in string theory predict other different universes than we predict (apart from themselves)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, astrophysics, astronomy

In string theory there are a huge number of possible universes. But if these universes have different properties would this mean that each of them have their own landscape of possible universes, predicting more different universes than us (apart from their own universe, including it in their landscape)

Comment: How would we even begin to ascertain such statements experimentally? String theorists have done a remarkable job at selling their creed to the general public but so far string theory has not predicted anything even remotely measurable.

Answer (score 1):

The string landscape is due to parameters called [moduli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_(physics)) that are related to the compactification having a range of discrete values. Calculating the number of possible combinations of these values gives us the figure of $10^{500}$ often cited as the size of the landscape. A particular universe has a particular choice of the moduli.

So it is not the case that each universe would have its own landscape. Rather that each universe is a point in the landscape that underlies all the universes.

We should note that while the [KKLT approach that leads to the landscape](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0301240) is well motivated, the idea that multiple universes exist is still highly speculative. You should not just assume that this is the case.